# Find the number of ways giving name tags such that there exist a student who don't exit the table after 4 operations.

Tags: combinatorics, analysis

**Question:**

> There are $n$ students sitting at a round table. You collect all $ n $ name tags and give them back arbitrarily. Each student gets one of the $n$ name tags. Now the $n$ students repeat following operation:
>
> - The students who have their own name tags leave the table. The other students give their name tags to the student who is sitting to their right.
>
> Find the number of ways of giving out the name tags such that there is a student who doesn't leave the table after $4$ repetitions of the operation.

I see some discussion that it is not true, but I think their result is true (because my English is not very good, so I only use Chinese say, that's you know what I mean). And I think this is an interesting problem. Now I can't have important key idea for this problem:**Final Korean Mathematical Olympiad 2014, #3**, and can see
[mathlinks](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=3438512&sid=94d106f9ff7ac3385f2ad8f3774e66b7#p3438512):

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't get as far as you probably want, but it may help somebody.  Let the number of students after one round be $p$, after two rounds be $q$, three rounds be $r$, and four rounds be $s$.  At the end of round three we have $r-s$ students with their own nametags and $s$ students with a derangement of theirs.  The derangement can be chosen in (the closest natural to) $\frac {s!}e=\lfloor \frac {s!}e+\frac 12 \rfloor$ ways.  We can select the students that leave in ${n \choose p}{p \choose q}{q \choose r}{r \choose s}$ ways, so the final result is $$\sum_{p=2}^n\sum_{q=2}^p\sum_{r=2}^q\sum_{s=2}^r {n \choose p}{p \choose q}{q \choose r}{r \choose s}\left \lfloor \frac {s!}e+\frac 12 \right \rfloor$$ where the sum starts from $2$ because you can't have just one student left.  The last term in the sum is zero for $s=1$